# Grammatical sentence

Tags: grammaticality

Is the sentence below grammatical?

I.e. 'The uncertainties *inherent in or in the form of* weather, yields, prices, global market and other factors that impact farming can cause wide swings in farm income.' Thanks

Kins

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, it is valid: your sentence has an agent 'the uncertainties' and object 'wide swings'.

The only concern is regarding how parsible it is. You introduce an unnecessary disjunctive 'in or in the' which may be avoided for fluency through selection of one embedded phrase. Perhaps, in place of a propositional clause 'that impact...', you may wish to construct a consequential phrase:

Impacts on farming due to uncertainties in the form of weather, yields, prices or global market can cause wide swings in farms' income.

Comment: Hello, Heliconaut. I'd substitute 'regarding' for 'in the form of'. But a sensible rewrite. However, the question is off-topic as _proofreading_, as it doesn't ask about a particular usage.